# I get error: name cannot be found in the name scope of - When moving from page to page in an MVVMLight application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have an `MVVMLight` multi-page application which has two pages, I can navigate from one page to the other by clicking the respective buttons.

In the second page, I have a loader animation that is triggered every time something is typed in a `textBox` field. Everything is working fine; from the first page I can go to the second page then you type something in the `textBox` and the animation starts. The problem is that if I go to the second page, then I go back to the first page and then I go to the second page again and type something in the `textBox` I get an error that says that the name of the loader doesn't exist, the funny thing is that I don't get this error until I leave the page and come back.

Any idea why the animation stops working after leaving the page and coming back?

**EDIT**: Here is the link to a complete project.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yf87shw5rzxtxen/AAClTesIGpLKl6IzV-6pjfEfa?dl=0

To replicate error do the following...

1. Download and open application.
2. Go to page 2.
3. Type something in the textBox (animation should start).
4. Go back to page 1, do nothing.
5. Go to page 2 again and try typing something in the textBox (you should see the error here).

### Error:

> > Additional information: 'rectangleLoader' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'TwoViews.Views.SecondView'.

[image]

### XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="TwoViews.Views.SecondView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="300"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangleLoader" Fill="#FFB2B2FF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="26,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="248"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxFileName" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                     Height="35" Width="180" 
                     Margin="26,125,0,0" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                     Text="{Binding InputFileNameChanged, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="18"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

### SecondView.xaml.cs

```
namespace TwoViews.Views
{
    public partial class SecondView : UserControl
    {
        private Storyboard loaderStoryboard;

        public SecondView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Messenger.Default.Register<MessageSearchStatus>(this, messageSearchStatus => ReceivedSearchStatus(messageSearchStatus));

            /// Animation for loader
            DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            myDoubleAnimation.From = 100;
            myDoubleAnimation.To = 0;
            myDoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.1));
            myDoubleAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
            myDoubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

            loaderStoryboard = new Storyboard();
            loaderStoryboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimation, rectangleLoader.Name);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(Rectangle.WidthProperty));
        }

        private void ReceivedSearchStatus(MessageSearchStatus message)
        {
            loaderStoryboard.Begin(this, true);
        }

        /// I manually stop the animation before going to other screens
        private void stopAnimation_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           loaderStoryboard.Stop(this);
        }

    }
}
```

### ViewModel

```
namespace TwoViews.ViewModels
{
    public class SecondViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string _inputFileName;

        public string InputFileNameChanged
        {
            get { return _inputFileName; }
            set {
                // send message to start animation everytime the textBox changes
                Messenger.Default.Send<MessageSearchStatus>(new MessageSearchStatus { isSearchingFile = true });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<s>Please note that in my code I'm not showing the code that stops the animation.</s>

Again, the animation works fine until the user leaves the page where the animation is and comes back.

Thanks!

Comment: "Please note that in my code I'm not showing the code that stops the animation." Why not? You should provide a MCVE of your issue if you want anyone to be able to point out where your issue is: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I didn't post it because the error was pointing me to the rectangle I'm using to represent the loader so I thought that it was irrelevant but now I truly believe that what is causing the error is the `animation`  because I tried accessing other properties of the 'rectangleLoader' in the method where I'm getting the error and I don't get any errors. BTW, I'm manually stopping the animation before going to a different view as follow... `loaderStoryboard.Stop(this);`. See updated code.

Comment: @mm8 - Here is the link to the complete project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yf87shw5rzxtxen/AAClTesIGpLKl6IzV-6pjfEfa?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI - The issue appeared to be the `Storyboard` I was using with the animation. Removed the `Storyboard` and everything work fine.

### SecondView.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using TwoViews.Models;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace TwoViews.Views
{
    public partial class SecondView : UserControl
    {
        private DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation;

        public SecondView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Messenger.Default.Register<MessageSearchStatus>(this, messageSearchStatus => ReceivedSearchStatus(messageSearchStatus));

            /// Animation for loader
            myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            myDoubleAnimation.From = 100;
            myDoubleAnimation.To = 0;
            myDoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.1));
            myDoubleAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
            myDoubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        }

        private void ReceivedSearchStatus(MessageSearchStatus message)
        {
            rectangleLoader.BeginAnimation(Rectangle.WidthProperty, myDoubleAnimation);
        }

        private void stopAnimation_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            rectangleLoader.BeginAnimation(Rectangle.WidthProperty, null);
        }
    }
}
```